# Need a jquery newsticker (scrolling/running text) horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know a great jquery horizontal newsticker?

Like:
http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

But without the white space.. Like an endless loop. And it should be possible for it to run very slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the link given?  You can get rid of the white space by editing the css attached.

Here is another [version](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/) this one seems to scroll infinitely.

With both you might have to modify a style to get the look you are looking for.

Comment: Editing the left attribute will eliminate the white space at the beginning of the scroll. But what about the white space at the end? The whole text need to be scrolled before it starts over..