# Parsing json text, then displaying it on a webpage

Tags: json, parsing

I am working with StreamOn, a streaming audio provider to distribute my audio stream for an online radio station. They make current "now playing" song information available on their servers (they provide me with the URL containing this information). Here is the data that is displayed when I go to that URL:

```
{
  "interval": {
    "id": 0,
    "starts_at": 1306738563270,
"ends_at": 1306738735270
  },
  "identifier": "Music-FS680",
  "category": "music",
  "original_category": "Music",
  "buy_link": "",
  "title": "I'm That Kind of Girl",
  "artist": "Patty Loveless",
  "album": "On Down the Line",
  "publisher": "UMG Recordings, Inc.",
  "itunes_song_id": "1290089",
  "album_art": {
    "src": "http://www.streamon.fm/player/getAlbumArt.php?u=http://a6.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/016/Features/20/41/7b/dj.twfxwryv.170x170-75.jpg",
    "width": 170,
    "height": 170,
    "alt": "On Down the Line",
    "link": ""
  },
  "next_song": "Little Bitty by Alan Jackson",
  "next_buy_link": "",
  "next_album_art": {
    "src": "http://www.streamon.fm/player/getAlbumArt.php?u=http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/025/Features/b5/cb/0b/dj.frlbluta.170x170-75.jpg",
    "width": 170,
    "height": 170,
    "alt": "Everything I Love",
    "link": ""
  },
  "banner": {
    "src": "",
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "alt": "",
    "link": ""
  }
}
```

I need to take that dynamic data, and cleanly display it on my homepage so that it looks like this:

```
Title:  I'm That Kind of Girl
Artist:  Parry Loveless
Album:  On Down the Line
```

I know this is text parsing, but I can't seem to figure out what type of text parsing method I need to use.

Comment: Have you any experience with programming languages? Server-side (PHP) or client-side (javascript?). Should the text manually be parsed (e.g. you update the title, artist and album manually) or automatically (e.g. a webpage should be retrieved and processed automatically)

Comment: I have some experience with javascript. The text will need to be automatically parsed. The JSON data is updated every time a new song begins playing.

Comment: @Luke: how does that text get on your page? Can you control the output? If you've a server-language, that'd be preferred since non-javascript users can see the songs too.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. The JSON data is available on an external server. I would need to parse that data and then display it on a page on my web server.

Comment: @Luke: what programming languages are supported on your server on which this webpage with song+artist+album is hosted? Would you mind posting a link to that JSON data?

Comment: Here's a link: http://wtsh.streamon.fm/card

Comment: @Luke: again, what server language is supported? You cannot do a cross-site request due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Can you post your server address or hosting provider?

Comment: My hosting provider is GoDaddy.

Comment: @LUke: GoDaddy supports PHP, see my answer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Please see my response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's JSON. Various parsers for different languages are available at http://json.org/

GoDaddy supports PHP as server-side language. A quick-and-dirty way to get parse the JSON response from an external server. Save the below code with a `.php` extension (like `currently_playing.php`):

```
<?php
// retrieve the contents of the URL
$ch = curl_init('http://wtsh.streamon.fm/card');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// parses the HTTP response and checks if the title exist
if (($json = json_decode($res)) && $json->title) {
    echo 'Title: '  . htmlspecialchars($json->title ) . '<br>';
    echo 'Artist: ' . htmlspecialchars($json->artist) . '<br>';
    echo 'Album: '  . htmlspecialchars($json->album ) . '<br>';
} else {
    echo 'No information available, please check again later';
}
?>
```

Usually, you would do some caching of the result, updating the song information every 10 seconds should be fine.

It appears that the response contains data on the end time of the song (in milliseconds). A better approach would then be checking if this time has passed, and if so, update the cache.

```
<?php // filename: current_song.php
$json = null;
$cache = 'song.json';
// if a cache exists and the time has not passed, use it
if (file_exists($cache)) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    if ($json->interval && $json->interval->ends_at / 1000 < time()) {
        // expired, discard json
        $json = null;
    }
}
// if there is no usuable cache
if (!$json) {
    // retrieve the contents of the URL
    $ch = curl_init('http://wtsh.streamon.fm/card');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($res);
    // if the title exists, assume the result to be valid
    if ($json && $json->title) {
        // cache it
        $fp = fopen('song.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $res);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $json = null;
    }
}
if ($json) {
    $info = array();
    // contains the time in milliseconds
    $info['wait_ms'] = $json->interval->ends_at - 1000 * microtime(true);
    $info['title']   = $json->title ;
    $info['artist']  = $json->artist;
    $info['album']   = $json->album ;
    $info['image']   = $json->album_art;
    // display a JSON response for the HTML page
    echo json_encode($info);
}
?>
```

To embed it in a HTML page, use:

```
<img id="song_image"><br>
Title:  <span id="song_title">-</span><br>
Artist: <span id="song_artist">-</span><br>
Album:  <span id="song_album">-</span>
<script>
(function () {
    // we need a JSON parser, if it does not exist, load it
    if (typeof JSON == "undefined") {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        // json2.js retrieved from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
        s.src = "json2.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head").appendChild(s);
    }
})();
var song_ends = 0;
function update_song () {
    if ((new Date).getTime() < song_ends) {
        // use cached result as the song has not ended yet
        return;
    }
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // IE compatbility:
    var textContent = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var song = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            if (song.title) {
                var img = document.getElementById("song_image");
                img.alt = song.image.alt;
                img.src = song.image.src;
                img.width = song.image.width;
                img.height = song.image.height;
                document.getElementById("song_title")[textContent]  = song.title ;
                document.getElementById("song_artist")[textContent] = song.artist;
                document.getElementById("song_album")[textContent]  = song.album ;
                // store the end date in javascript date format
                song_ends = (new Date).getTime() + song.wait_ms;
            }
        }
    };
    req.open('get', 'current_song.php', true);
    req.send(null);
}
// poll for changes every second
setInterval(update_song, 1000);
// and update the song information
update_song();
</script>
```

Comment: That works great! How do I setup the automatic 10 second updates?

Comment: Figured out how to embed it in an html page... that was a stupid question. Thanks for the info on the updates! One more question and I will leave you alone.  The JSON data includes a URL for an image of the album cover. How would I get that in the code so the album art is displayed next to the text info?

Comment: @Lekensteyn:  When I paste that code in the body section of my html page, all that is shown is this text on this page:    http://lbrannonent.com/test.html

Comment: @luke: oops, I put an excess tag in it. Can you spot it? :)

Comment: @Lekensteyn:  Ah, yes the extra </script> tag.  It's still not working though. I've updated it with the new code at http://lbrannonent.com/test.html

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Did that... still nothing.

Comment: I think you've an old PHP version which was not bundled with JSON. See the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/q/2900511/427545

Comment: @Luke: 5.3 is the current version. PHP >= 5.2.0 is bundled with JSON support by default./

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I am running version 5.2.14 as shown here:  http://lbrannonent.com/phpinfo.php    Is there a workaround to get this to work with my current version of PHP? I have no control over these servers, so I can't upgrade to 5.3

Comment: @Luke: strange, JSON seems to be available and I just noticided that the error is on the Javascript side. See the edit please, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: No problem! I appreciate your help this far. However, it is still not working as intended. I updated everything with the latest code, but it is still not displaying to data on the html page.  http://lbrannonent.com/current_song.php  http://lbrannonent.com/test.html

Comment: The PHP part is fine, but the JS code was missing a `{`. I used JSLint now to check for syntax errors and typos, and it seems to work now.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for your help! You are indeed a lifesaver!

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Is there a way to specify an image to use for the album art is album art is unavailable? That is, if the "album_art" field is empty at http://wtsh.streamon.fm/card to use a placeholder image.

Comment: @Luke, no offense, but have you tried something yourself? If you can do a bit JS, you can modify the code to check whether `image.src` is empty or not.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I am just not very fluent in javascript. I can modify existing script, but when it comes to writing new script I am lost. I'm more versed in html, css, etc. I completely understand if you don't want to help.

Comment: @Luke: you've to put the `img.src`, `img.alt`, `img.width` and `img.height` after a `if(img.src){` block, and put an `}else{img.src="default.png";/*other attributes here*/}` after

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thanks for the reply. Seems to be working, but the only issue I am having is that when I load the page, it always loads the default image I defined, even if there is an image defined. After a few minutes (when the JSON information changes) it will load the correct image. Does the script not have enough time to load the information before it replaces the art with the default image? Do you mind taking a look at the source at http://lbrannonent.com/BigCountry247/index.html   (I'm still working on the marquee on that page... that's why it looks so ridiculous)

Comment: @Luke: oh, `if(img.src){` has to be `if(song.image.src){`. I suggest putting the script after the HTML (before `</body>`)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Fantastic! Again, thank you so much for your help. You really have been a life saver. Now if I can just get these crazy marquees to only scroll if there is overflow! Again, thank you. -Luke

Comment: @Luke: `<marquee>` is deprecated, consider alternatives. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5988803/427545 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2991621/427545. If this answers your question, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/150311) it.

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON parsing, not text parsing. Depending on the language you use to decode that JSON, you could use some ready made functions to obtain the values you want in a very straight forward and easy way.

In PHP, you could use the [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

In javascript, json is native, see [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) how to access your data members

Comment: Can you recommend a good JSON parser? I just need to display the parsed data on an html page.